# try-with-resource without declaring variable

Tags: java, try-catch

I want to use try-with-resource to switch context but it seem try() can't use a resource without declaring a variable which makes the code less elegant. e.g.

```
class SwitchContext implements Closeable {
   public SwitchContext(String newContext) {
     //Set new context to local thread
   }

   public void close() {
     //Restore old context to local thread
   }
```

and the usage:

```
String func() {
  try (new SwitchContext(newContext)) {
     //Do something
     return "dummy";
  }

void func2() {
  try (new SwitchContext(newContext)) {
     //Do something
  }
```

But I get Syntext error on the try(). Only if I write it like this:
`try (SwitchContext c = new SwitchContext(newContext)) {`
It passes compilation.
What is the most elegant way to do it?

**Update**

Since in some of the answers people didn't understand what I'm trying to do I'll try to explain better. I'm trying to do the following logic in a more elegant way:

```
void func() {
   Context old = ContextUtil.getCurrentContext();
   try() {
       ContextUtil.setContext(A)
       //Do something or call other methods
       //Any method than need the context use ContextUtil.getCurrentContext()
   } finally () {
      ContextUtil.setContext(old)
   }
}
```

Comment: What would be the point of that? If you don't assign it to a variable, you cannot use it inside the try-block hence you might as well not declare it at all.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS If it has some setup and cleanup in its constructor and close() method that is necessary for the code inside the try block.

Comment: Assigning it to a variable seems like the easiest solution. Or maybe using a traditional try/finally block instead of the closeable object would be more suitable.

Comment: @khelwood Okay, I didn't think of that. Still seems like a weird edge case and not really what a closable resource is normally used for.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Life is full of weird edge cases.

Comment: Wondering: do you still have questions regarding the answers you got? If not, and your problem is solved, please consider accepting one of the answer at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Do not discard the new object’s reference

The `new` command returns a reference to the newly instantiated object. Your code attempt would discard that reference. So none of your code to follow could access that instantiated resource object. It makes no sense to create a resource object that cannot be used.

The solution is to create a reference variable into which we can capture the newly created resource object’s reference.

```java
String func() {
    try (
        SwitchContext context = new SwitchContext( newContext ) ;
    ) {
    // Do something with that resource.
    String result = context.calculate() ;
    return result ;
}
// At this point, `SwitchContext#close` has been called and executed, closing our resource object.
```

You commented, « It is not a truly new resource ». If you mean the object you want to utilize and automatically close has already been instantiated, use a different form of try-with-resources.

In later versions of Java, your try-with-resources can access, and automatically close, a resource that was instantiated earlier.

```java
SwitchContext context = new SwitchContext( newContext ) ;
… more code …
String func() {
    try (
       context
    ) {
    // Do something with that resource.
    String result = context.calculate() ;
    return result ;
}
// At this point, `SwitchContext#close` has been called and executed, closing our resource object.
```

## Try-with-resources is all about calling `close`

Keep in mind that the entire point to using try-with-resources is to have the JVM automatically call the resources’ `close` method. If calling `close` is not your intention, use a different flow-of-control structure in your code.

Comment: It is not a truly new resource. I just need a mechanism to switch context back

Comment: @user3369398 No, calling `new` *always* instantiates a new object. If instantiation is not your intention, you have a design problem.

Comment: You are right that new always create a new object but I don't need this reference since the close() doesn't really close anything but switch the context back. So the garbage collector can handle the new reference. See my update to understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user3369398 If you are using close() to do something other than close the resources used by the object, you are misusing it.

Answer (score 1):

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources

From the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Long story short: the syntax of a language is what it is. And when the language asks for a **declaration**, then that is what you have to put in your code.

Or, when you want the formal stuff, check out the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

```
TryWithResourcesStatement:
try ResourceSpecification Block [Catches] [Finally]

ResourceSpecification:
( ResourceList [;] )

ResourceList:
Resource {; Resource}

Resource:
LocalVariableDeclaration
VariableAccess
VariableAccess:
ExpressionName
FieldAccess
```